# CompareFaces Throws Error When Using Cropped Image

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-rekognition

I am using Amazon Rekognition to compare faces between images loaded into memory in python, but when I try to pass cropped images, it throws an error:
    `InvalidParameterException: An error occurred (InvalidParameterException) when calling the CompareFaces operation: Request has Invalid Parameters`

an example of the code being used is:

```
ret, frame = vid.read()
frame = cv2.resize(frame1, (0,0), fx=.5, fy=.5)
frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
content1 = cv2.imencode('.jpg',frame[:,0:540,:])[1].tostring()
content2 = cv2.imencode('.jpg',frame[:,1:540,:])[1].tostring()
awsclient=boto3.client('rekognition','us-west-2',
                    aws_access_key_id='********************',
                    aws_secret_access_key='*****************')
awsresponse = awsclient.compare_faces(SourceImage={'Bytes': content1},
                                  TargetImage={'Bytes': content2})
```

The last line throws the error. However, if I submit:

```
awsresponse = awsclient.compare_faces(SourceImage={'Bytes': content1},
                                  TargetImage={'Bytes': content1})
```

There is no error and faces are matched. Does anybody have ideas as to the reason for this error?

A full trace for this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidParameterException                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-227-60437107e6df> in <module>()
      8                         aws_secret_access_key='***********')
      9 awsresponse = awsclient.compare_faces(SourceImage={'Bytes': content1},
---> 10                                   TargetImage={'Bytes': content2})

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/botocore/client.py in _api_call(self, *args, **kwargs)
    312                     "%s() only accepts keyword arguments." % py_operation_name)
    313             # The "self" in this scope is referring to the BaseClient.
--> 314             return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
    315 
    316         _api_call.__name__ = str(py_operation_name)

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/botocore/client.py in _make_api_call(self, operation_name, api_params)
    610             error_code = parsed_response.get("Error", {}).get("Code")
    611             error_class = self.exceptions.from_code(error_code)
--> 612             raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
    613         else:
    614             return parsed_response

InvalidParameterException: An error occurred (InvalidParameterException) when calling the CompareFaces operation: Request has Invalid Parameters
```

Comment: Would you mind posting the full stack trace for us?

Comment: If you crop a picture and save it (with some external app), and then load that file, does it still crash, or is the problem that `cv2.imencode('.jpg',frame[:,0:540,:])[1].tostring()` is not returning the bytes of a jpeg encoding?

Comment: @zerocool I added the full stack trace. It seems that the error is actually very unpredictable, as it returns an error when cropped from `[:,1:540,:]` but not when cropped from `[:,1:340,:]` but also returns an error when cropped from `[:,2:530,:]`